# Best practices for managing software releases with CI/CD with distributed software components running on a customer on-site machine?

Tags: continuous-integration, release-management, distributed-system

I'm looking for some resources on learning how to best manage our software releases in an efficient manner, as our current method slows release schedules down.

My current team produces and administers industrial machines that (computer-wise) consist of at least one PC, running several custom software components that communicate with each other via a proprietary RPC protocol. Some machines also have other PCs as part of the machine, which communicate with the main PC in the same manner.

We distribute entire sets of software that are known to work with each other to customer machines, after going through a manual integration testing process (I acknowledge that this part needs to be also automated). We also sometimes produce experimental builds for customers that consent to test for features. Software bundles are installed manually to customer machines via remote access software.

We currently use Git for software version control with GitLab (with each component having its own repository, for the most part), and CI/CD pipelines that lint, test and produce executable builds for each of the software components - but we don't currently have a way to control versions for entire groups of software via CI/CD - this is done manually. We have a script that grabs the latest versions of each of the software on the main branches, but it's somewhat fragile and doesn't allow us to specify which commit or branches to pull in. We don't have a reliable way to create a test version of experimental code across multiple components via CI/CD (and locally) without transferring all of the code to our test harness manually, which can be tedious in projects that cross all components.

I've been looking for a way to efficiently keep track of the software versions for constellations of specific versions of software components that need to work together without doing so manually. Is there a well accepted solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

There are several best practices and tools you could adopt to better manage your software releases and effectively work with CI/CD in a distributed system context. I'll touch on few potential solutions you can consider:

**1. Dependency Management:**

This is crucial in systems with many components that rely on specific versions of one another. Look into dependency management tools like Go Modules, Maven, Gradle, or Npm, which can help you specify and track the exact versions of dependencies your project needs.

**2. Semantic Versioning:**

Consider adopting semantic versioning for your software components. This will help keep track of versions in a meaningful way, where version numbers and the way they change convey meaning about the underlying changes in the project.

**3. Monorepo vs Multirepo:**

The debate between monorepo (storing all your code in a single repository) and multirepo (multiple repositories for different components/services) is well-documented. A monorepo could potentially help you manage dependencies better, simplify your pipelines and promote code re-use. However, it also comes with its own challenges such as increased repository size, slower CI/CD pipeline, etc.

**4. Binary Repository Manager:**

For managing releases, consider using a binary repository manager like JFrog Artifactory or Sonatype Nexus. These tools can store and manage your binaries, making them available for deployment and ensuring that you deploy exactly what you tested.

**5. CI/CD Enhancements:**

For your CI/CD pipeline, consider using a configuration as code approach. This will allow you to version your CI/CD configuration just like your application code. GitLab's CI/CD pipeline is quite advanced and supports this.

**6. GitOps:**

GitOps is a method to do Kubernetes cluster management and application delivery. It works by using Git as a single source of truth for declarative infrastructure and applications. In your case, you can use GitOps principles to maintain a specific state of your software components and their versions.

**7. Automated Testing:**

As you mentioned, automating your testing process is crucial. Look into automated integration testing and end-to-end testing. Tools like Jenkins, GitLab CI, and others can help.

**8. Configuration Management:**

Consider using a configuration management tool like Ansible, Chef, or Puppet. These tools can help manage and automate deployment to your customer machines.

**9. Containerization and Orchestration:**

If possible, you might want to look into using Docker for containerizing your software components and Kubernetes for orchestration. This can simplify the deployment process and ensure the same environment across different stages.

**10. Feature Flags:**

For managing experimental builds, consider implementing feature flags in your code. This will allow you to enable or disable features without having to deploy new versions.

There isn't a one-size-fits-all solution, but rather a combination of best practices and tooling. I'd recommend taking a step-by-step approach to implementing these changes. Identify areas where improvements can have the most impact and start with those, and then progressively improve other areas.

Comment: Is this answer generated by chatGPT? If so, that is discoraged: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9448/avoid-using-chatgpt-or-other-ai-powered-solutions-to-generate-answers-to-questio as like in this case, it often generates answers that miss the insight that is expected of answers on this site.